# Framer motion does not do exit animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

why when I set the exit property of framer motion to my html elements they don't animate when they are removed from the DOM?

this is a examble of my code:

```
<motion.div 
   initial={{opacity: 0, y: -500}} 
   animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0, scale: 0.9}} 
   exit={{opacity: 0, y: -500}}
   >
  Very Code...
</motion.div>
```

I tried putting a reference to it with the useRef and mounting it in the DOM with .mount() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to wrap the exiting component in an `AnimatePresence` tag.**

From [the docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/):

> `AnimatePresence` allows components to animate out when they're removed  from the React tree.
>
> It's required to enable exit animations because React lacks a lifecycle method that:
>
> - Notifies components when they're going to be unmounted and
> - Allows them to defer that unmounting until after an operation is complete (for instance an animation).

**You'll also need to add a `key` prop ([docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/##exit-animations)).**

> Direct children must each have a unique key prop so AnimatePresence can track their presence in the tree.

Example:

```
<AnimatePresence>
  {isVisible && (
    <motion.div
      key="modal" 
      initial={{opacity: 0, y: -500}} 
      animate={{opacity: 1, y: 0, scale: 0.9}} 
      exit={{opacity: 0, y: -500}}
    >
      Very Code...
    </motion.div>
  )}
</AnimatePresence>
```